# Flutter: How to access a member in a static method in the same class

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this class with a static method (to run a compute isolate)

```
class ResizeImage {

  ResizeImage(this.tempPath) {
    sTempPath = tempPath;

    print('main()resizeMyProImage.dart...IN CLASS.........imgFile tempPath: '+tempPath);
    print('main()resizeMyProImage.dart...IN CLASS.........imgFile sTempPath: '+sTempPath);
  }

  String tempPath;
  static String sTempPath

....

  static File decodeProfileImage(File imageFile) {
// get sTempPath here...


    print('decodeProfileImage...decodeImage.dart...IN CLASS.......well.tempPath......hit with: '+sTempPath);

//    Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
//    Im.Image smallerImage = Im.copyResize(image, 150); // choose the size here, it will maintain aspect ratio
//    return new File(sTempPath+'thumbnail.jpg')
//      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(smallerImage, quality: 85));
  }
```

I am instantiating like so in another class...

```
ResizeImage resizeImage = new ResizeImage(tempPath);
      print('uploadFile >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>....hit begin 000 resizeImage.tempPath: '+resizeImage.tempPath);

      File myFile;
      if (isProfilePic) myFile = (await resizeImage.resizeMyProImage(file));
```

Error:

```
Isolate (389190561) 'main.dart:_spawn()' exited with an error
E/flutter ( 2369): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 2369): Invalid argument(s)
E/flutter ( 2369): #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core/runtime/libstring_patch.dart:246:57)
```

How do I access tempPath member from the static decodeProfileImage. -Thanks for reading.

Comment: To access a static method from within the class where it is declared just use it's name. You can prefix it with the class name but that is redundant. It work work for `compute` though. See my answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the help.  If I remove static I get the Error: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'decodeProfileImage':.)

Comment: It must be a top-level function. This means you need to move it out from the class.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you update your answer with some pseudo code on what the class structure would look like with a top level function ? thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer but it might be a bit off because I don't understand your code or what exactly you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer quick a question, is it possible to pass a second argument (String) to the compute isolate ? I think my problem would be resolved with a ...compute(nameOfMethod, imageFile, pathOfCacheString) ?

Comment: You can pass a List or Map that contain as many values as you want.

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT:

### This has now changed, callbacks can be static methods: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ComputeCallback.html.

I haven't tried and I haven't found a related changelog. I hope the docs are correct.

## Original

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html

> The callback argument must be a top-level function, not a closure or an instance or static method of a class.

note especially

> not a ... or static method of a class

```
Future doSomethingInIsolate() async {
  var result = await compute(decodeProfileImage, data);
}


File decodeProfileImage(File imageFile) {
  var resize = ResizeImage();
  resize...
}

class ResizeImage {

  ResizeImage(this.tempPath) {
     ...
  }

}
```